# Support for JSON schema draft 03

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, json.net, jsonschema

I am using Json.NET for my project in visual studio 2013 (I am aware that VS2013 has built-in support for JSON, but Json.NET seems easier to use), but the built-in JSON editor does not seem to accurately provide code completion for JSON schema draft 03, and Json.NET does not seem to support JSON schema draft 04.

Is there any way to get these two modules to work together?  As far as I can tell, there's no way to get Json.NET to work with schema draft 04, so my question is mostly this:

How can I get the VS2013 JSON editor to use Intellisense and the associated code completion for JSON schema draft 03?

Answer (score 1):

**[Json.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)** has full support for Draft 3 and Draft 4.